# How to create an Object with private creator (like EGLContext) under PIE?

Tags: java, android, reflection, android-9.0-pie

This class is defined under Android:

```
public abstract class EGLObjectHandle {
    private final long mHandle;

    protected EGLObjectHandle(long handle) {
        mHandle = handle;
    }


    public long getNativeHandle() {
        return mHandle;
    }

}
```

and also

```
public class EGLContext extends EGLObjectHandle {
    private EGLContext(long handle) {
        super(handle);
    }

}
```

now my problem is that I want to create an **EGLContext with my handle.** How to do this? before I do it with the function below but it's not working anymore on **PIE**

```
  private android.opengl.EGLContext createSharedEGLContextObj(long handle) throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, NoSuchMethodException, InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> classType =Class.forName("android.opengl.EGLContext"); 
    Class<?>[] types = new Class[] { long.class };
    Constructor constructor=classType.getDeclaredConstructor(types);
    constructor.setAccessible(true);     
    Object object=constructor.newInstance(handle);
    return (android.opengl.EGLContext) object;
  }
```

I need an `EGLContext` because I need to pass it to a procedure who require an EGLContext parameter, like for example: `createEgl14( android.opengl.EGLContext sharedContext)`

Comment: You should extends your class from `EGLContext`

Comment: @Dred thanks but how to do this?

Comment: Why do you make the handle with JNI?

Comment: the framework did it like this, it's a native delphi app

Comment: Oh, also I think you meant "on PIE" and not "under PIE"

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much can't. According to [Android Restrictions](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) they have restricted JNI and reflection to only SDK interfaces.

I think your final option is [request a new feature](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces#feature-request) where they will change the constructor visibility to public.

Comment: no I absolutely need an instance of EGLContext because I need to pass it to a procedure who require an EGLContext parameter: "createEgl14(
      android.opengl.EGLContext sharedContext)"

Comment: Ok interesting, I edited the post to add another way but please explain why reflection fails

Comment: because on Pie reflection is now forbidden and it's make the app crash :( I m getting this handle from my delphi app (pascal code) through JNI interface and I want to share this handle (that is own by the delphi code) with the java code and for this I need to create an EGLContext

Comment: Well then you can create the EGLContext from JNI. using the "How to create an Object" link I gave you

Comment: Aie, so even with JNI I can't?

Comment: According to Android no, you can't even with JNI, sorry to have to give the bad news, I saw this isn't your first question about this

Comment: I m just curious, how even Android can create an EGLContext ? because as the creator is private noone even android can create this object

Comment: I am guessing they use Reflection or JNI as they are allowed to.